# Getting error while trying to find area of rectangle

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm completely beginner in `Python`
When I'm trying to find area of rectangle, I'm getting error. Here is my code:

```
# Python Program to find Area of a Rectangle
width = float(input('Enter width of rectangle : ') 
length = float(input('Enter length of rectangle : ')
#calculating Area
Area = width * length 
#calculating perimeter 
Perimeter = 2 * ( length + breadth )
print (' \n Area of Rectangle : ' Area)
```

Comment: Please post the code here, rather than the screenshot

Comment: Please insert your code or your question may be closed and you won't receive answers

Comment: # Python Program to find Area of a Rectangle

width = float(input('Enter width of rectangle : ')
length = float(input('Enter length of rectangle : ')

#calculating Area

Area = width * length

#calculating perimeter

Perimeter = 2 * ( length + breadth )

print (' \n Area of Rectangle : ' Area)

Comment: not here man:) I'm going to edit your question, please guide my edit to you!

Comment: You missed a parenthesis for `float` - that's why there's an error

Comment: Thanks @Gokul :)

Comment: Added @KeremCan :)

Comment: Check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), for next times. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks @KeremCan :*

Comment: and don't forget to mark the answer as accepted answer if you find the answer useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a bracket when calling the float function:

```
# Python Program to find Area of a Rectangle
width = float(input('Enter width of rectangle : ')) # add one more bracket here ...
length = float(input('Enter length of rectangle : ')) # and here
#calculating Area
Area = width * length 
#calculating perimeter 
Perimeter = 2 * ( length + breadth )
print (' \n Area of Rectangle : ' Area)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#Calculates the area of a rectangle

#Start

def areaOfRectangle(width, length):
    area = float(width) * float(length)
    print 'The Area of the Rectangle is {:}'. format(area)
    return area

width = input()
print 'Please give the width of the rectangle: {}'. format(width)

length = input()
print 'Please give the length of the rectangle: {}'. format(length)

areaOfRectangle(width, length)

#End
```

Hope, this is help!